# bigrquery: mean, max, min and sd extraction inside 5-95 quantiles using dplyr verbs doesn't work

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery, dbplyr, bigrquery

I try to make the mean, max, min and sd extraction inside 5-95 quantiles in a BigQuery server, but `dplyr` verbs don't work and the output error is: `x Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AS at [1:117] [invalidQuery]`

In my example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(bigrquery)
library(DBI)
library(googleAuthR)
bq_auth(email = "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com") 

projectid<-'helical-client-323918'
datasetid<-'spectra_calibration'
bq_conn <-  dbConnect(bigquery(), 
                      project = projectid,
                      dataset = datasetid, 
                      use_legacy_sql = FALSE
)
bigrquery::dbListTables(bq_conn) # List all the tables in BigQuery data set
#[1] "CMPC"
#

raw_spectra_CMPC <- dplyr::tbl(bq_conn, 
                               "CMPC") # connects to a table

glimpse(raw_spectra_CMPC) 
Rows: ??
Columns: 27
Database: BigQueryConnection
$ x          <dbl> -52.5502, -52.5501, -52.5501, -52.5501, -52.5501, -52.5500, -52.5500, -52.5500, -52.5500, -52.5500, -5~
$ y          <dbl> -30.8295, -30.8297, -30.8296, -30.8295, -30.8294, -30.8298, -30.8297, -30.8296, -30.8295, -30.8294, -3~
$ stand      <chr> "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A~
$ date       <chr> "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "201~
$ B2         <dbl> 213, 205, 181, 207, 216, 205, 165, 161, 173, 182, 181, 259, 227, 190, 153, 147, 160, 164, 194, 210, 18~
$ B3         <dbl> 361.0, 362.0, 346.0, 352.0, 369.0, 330.0, 290.0, 326.0, 334.0, 332.0, 325.0, 375.0, 352.0, 307.0, 281.~
$ B4         <dbl> 227.0, 233.0, 198.0, 207.0, 209.0, 227.0, 178.0, 164.0, 180.0, 207.0, 209.0, 267.0, 269.0, 194.0, 163.~
$ B8         <dbl> 3033.0, 3307.0, 3322.0, 3232.0, 3241.0, 3065.0, 3306.0, 3422.0, 3427.0, 3392.0, 3165.0, 3206.0, 2984.0~
$ NDVI       <dbl> 0.86074, 0.86836, 0.88750, 0.87962, 0.87884, 0.86209, 0.89782, 0.90853, 0.90019, 0.88497, 0.87611, 0.8~
$ SAVI       <dbl> 4549.379, 4960.386, 4982.905, 4847.897, 4861.397, 4597.380, 4958.915, 5132.925, 5140.417, 5087.903, 47~
$ SIPI       <dbl> 1.00499, 1.00911, 1.00544, 1.00000, 0.99769, 1.00775, 1.00416, 1.00092, 1.00216, 1.00785, 1.00947, 1.0~
$ SR         <dbl> 13.36123, 14.19313, 16.77778, 15.61353, 15.50718, 13.50220, 18.57303, 20.86585, 19.03889, 16.38647, 15~
$ RGI        <dbl> 0.62881, 0.64365, 0.57225, 0.58807, 0.56640, 0.68788, 0.61379, 0.50307, 0.53892, 0.62349, 0.64308, 0.7~
$ TVI        <int> 173720, 189600, 193360, 187300, 188320, 174400, 192160, 201960, 200980, 196100, 182000, 180660, 166220~
$ MSR        <dbl> 3.65530, 3.76738, 4.09607, 3.95140, 3.93792, 3.67453, 4.30964, 4.56792, 4.36336, 4.04802, 3.89147, 3.4~
$ PRI        <dbl> -0.25784, -0.27690, -0.31309, -0.25939, -0.26154, -0.23364, -0.27473, -0.33881, -0.31755, -0.29183, -0~
$ GNDVI      <dbl> 0.78727, 0.80267, 0.81134, 0.80357, 0.79557, 0.80560, 0.83871, 0.82604, 0.82239, 0.82170, 0.81375, 0.7~
$ PSRI       <dbl> -0.04418, -0.03901, -0.04455, -0.04486, -0.04937, -0.03361, -0.03388, -0.04734, -0.04494, -0.03685, -0~
$ GCI        <dbl> 7.40166, 8.13536, 8.60116, 8.18182, 7.78320, 8.28788, 10.40000, 9.49693, 9.26048, 9.21687, 8.73846, 7.~
$ ID_PROJETO <int> 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 24~
$ PROJETO    <chr> "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "AB~
$ CD_TALHAO  <chr> "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A"~
$ DATA_PLANT <chr> "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "200~
$ ESPECIE    <chr> "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SA~
$ ESPAC      <chr> "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2~
$ AGE_1      <dbl> 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, ~
$ AGE        <int> 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11~
```

But when I try to used my function:

```
quantis <- function(x) x > quantile(x, 0.05) & x < quantile(x, 0.95)
data_Q95 <- raw_spectra_CMPC  %>% 
  filter (across(B2:GCI, .fns = quantis)) %>%
  group_by(AGE, ESPAC) %>%
  summarise(across(B2:GCI, list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), max = ~ max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), min = ~ min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))
data_Q95
# <error/rlang_error>
# Job 'fc-vm-v1.job_41KNdnsYP_gws6avquMVeqjOC6_V.US' failed
# x Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AS at [1:117] [invalidQuery]
# Backtrace:
#   1. (function (x, ...) ...
#   2. dbplyr:::print.tbl_sql(x)
#   7. pillar:::format.tbl(x, ..., n = n, width = width, n_extra = n_extra)
#   8. pillar:::format_tbl(...)
#   9. pillar::tbl_format_setup(...)
#  11. pillar:::tbl_format_setup.tbl(...)
#  12. pillar:::df_head(x, n + 1)
#  14. dbplyr:::as.data.frame.tbl_sql(head(x, n))
#  17. bigrquery:::collect.tbl_BigQueryConnection(x, n = n)
#  18. bigrquery::bq_dataset_query(...)
#  19. bigrquery::bq_job_wait(job, quiet = quiet)
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Please, any help with a good way for me to make these extractions?  Is necessary to use SQL query too? I make some tests with my function in a *csv file before export to the BigQuery and works very well:

```
raw_spectra_CMPC_csv <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_ds_CSV.csv")
quantis <- function(x) x > quantile(x, 0.05) & x < quantile(x, 0.95)
data_Q95 <- raw_spectra_CMPC_csv  %>% 
  filter (across(B2:GCI, .fns = quantis)) %>%
  group_by(AGE, ESPAC) %>%
  summarise(across(B2:GCI, list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), max = ~ max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), min = ~ min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))
data_Q95
# # A tibble: 7 x 62
# # Groups:   AGE [7]
#     AGE ESPAC    B2_mean B2_max B2_min B2_sd B3_mean B3_max B3_min B3_sd B4_mean B4_max B4_min B4_sd B8_mean B8_max B8_min
#   <int> <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1    -2 4X1.85      125.   175    75    14.2    236.    312   199   18.6    129.    345   108.  12.6   3590.   4052   2189
# 2    -1 4X1.85      153.   300    67    34.0    282.    436   198.  34.3    166.    379   108.  30.7   3346.   4059   2208
# 3     0 4X1.85      419.   928.   71   274.     610.   1208   199  328.     730.   1668   109  535.    2933.   4069   2095
# 4     1 4X1.85      344.   683   129    83.4    510.    944   286   97.0    544.   1180   256  129.    2871.   3451   2115
# 5    11 3.5x2.14    137.   259    70    29.8    276.    467   199   38.4    160.    361   109   26.4   3665.   4069   2688
# 6    12 3.5x2.14    150.   298    67.5  23.6    267.    485   200   32.1    169.    421   109   26.2   3354.   4067   2293
# 7    13 3.5x2.14    130.   302    70    35.3    247.    482   200   30.0    144.    465   111   29.7   3833.   4069   3116
# # ... with 45 more variables: B8_sd <dbl>, NDVI_mean <dbl>, NDVI_max <dbl>, NDVI_min <dbl>, NDVI_sd <dbl>,
# #   SAVI_mean <dbl>, SAVI_max <dbl>, SAVI_min <dbl>, SAVI_sd <dbl>, SIPI_mean <dbl>, SIPI_max <dbl>, SIPI_min <dbl>,
# #   SIPI_sd <dbl>, SR_mean <dbl>, SR_max <dbl>, SR_min <dbl>, SR_sd <dbl>, RGI_mean <dbl>, RGI_max <dbl>, RGI_min <dbl>,
# #   RGI_sd <dbl>, TVI_mean <dbl>, TVI_max <dbl>, TVI_min <dbl>, TVI_sd <dbl>, MSR_mean <dbl>, MSR_max <dbl>,
# #   MSR_min <dbl>, MSR_sd <dbl>, PRI_mean <dbl>, PRI_max <dbl>, PRI_min <dbl>, PRI_sd <dbl>, GNDVI_mean <dbl>,
# #   GNDVI_max <dbl>, GNDVI_min <dbl>, GNDVI_sd <dbl>, PSRI_mean <dbl>, PSRI_max <dbl>, PSRI_min <dbl>, PSRI_sd <dbl>,
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this will fix the error but in general you should not use multiple `across` here. Instead apply multiple functions in one `across` i.e `summarise(across(B2:GCI, list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), max = ~ max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), min = ~ min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))`

Comment: Can you share a complete sample dataset so the issue can be easily reproduced by the community?

Comment: Please, @RiccoD any tips for a reproducible BigQuery dataset? I don't find anything on the web.

Comment: You were able to provide the necessary details on your edited  question! Thanks for that =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing your code and I noticed that R code is not properly translated to BQ query.

1. Use `sd(.x)` since by default BQ ([STTD_DEV](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#stddev_samp)) ignores the null values.
2. The function `quantis` is not created in BQ, thus it does not do its job and errors out. I'm not sure if R supports use of functions to BQ.

What I could suggest is instead of using native R operations use SQL statements to prevent incorrect translation of R to BigQuery operations. You can try creating a [user defined function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) (your `quantis` function) in BQ. In your select statement perform mean, max and sd on your fields. Filter using your UDF(quantis), group by age and espac. You can also try creating a VIEW that achieves most of your goal including WHERE clause on quantile. You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/use-r-bigquery) for reference on how to use BigQuery in R.